# Draw to PictureBox from other function

Tags: c#, picturebox

I am trying to draw to a PictureBox from another function which is **not the paint event**!

Here is what it looks like:

```
public void Draw(ref PictureBox picture_box)
{
    Graphics graphics = picture_box.CreateGraphics();

    for (int i = 0; i < ship.Count; ++i)
    {
        if (ship[i].form == FORM.RECTANGLE)
        {
            graphics.FillRectangle(ship[i].color, ship[i].rectangle);
        }
        else if (ship[i].form == FORM.ELLIPSE)
        {
            graphics.FillEllipse(ship[i].color, ship[i].rectangle);
        }
    }

    graphics.Dispose();
    picture_box.Refresh();
}
```

(ship is a List of ship_part classes, which contain a Rectangle, a FORM enum (RECTANGLE, ELLIPSE) and a Brush)

I call Draw in the Form's constructor :

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    spaceship ship;
    ship_part part;

    ship = new spaceship();

    part = new ship_part(); //constructor initializes form to RECTANGLE and color to Brushes.Black
    part.rectangle = new Rectangle(50, 50, 10, 10);

    ship.ship.Add(part);

    ship.Draw(ref pictureBox1);
}
```

The problem is that the Rectangle is not drawn.

What I have tried so far :

I thought there might be a problem with this line :

```
Graphics graphics = picture_box.CreateGraphics();
```

I think that I am not writing to the actual Graphics object that belongs to the PictureBox so I made my Draw function return the Graphics object that gets modified. Then I called the Draw function from the Picture Box Paint Event and tried to assign that Graphics object to the one that gets passed as parameter in the PaintEventArgs. But the PaintEvenArgs.Graphics object is read only.

Thanks!

Comment: You are just splattering pixels, they don't last.  They don't even start with your code, you splatter when the window isn't visible yet.  A Winforms tutorial is pretty essential when you struggle with the basics like this.

Comment: `CreateGraphics` not the right way to draw your stuff

Comment: Yeah, that's what I expected! How is it done then ?